# Guice + Jersey: Add all resources and providers without bind to Jersey Servlet

Tags: java, jersey, guice

Im currently working on an jersey application using Jersey 1.8 in conjunction with Guice 3.0 for DI for my JPA. This works pretty well with one major issue which I wasn't able to overcome:

I have to manually add all Jersey Resource classes to the JerseyServletModule using bind:

```
@Override
protected Injector getInjector() {
    return Guice.createInjector(new JerseyServletModule() {

        @Override
        protected void configureServlets() {

            install(new JpaPersistModule("DBName"));
            filter("/*").through(PersistFilter.class);

            /* bind the REST resources and serve*/
            bind(Hello.class);
            serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);

        }
    });
}
```

I would like to be able to ommit the use of bind for every single resource and provider and found in the jersey-guice doc a remark: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.8/contribs/jersey-guice/com/sun/jersey/guice/spi/container/servlet/package-summary.html

It basically states that one can pass the registration of jersey resources to the jersey servlet. However i was not able to manage this using said method:

```
@Override
     protected Injector getInjector() {
         return Guice.createInjector(new JerseyServletModule() {

             @Override
             protected void configureServlets() {
                 bind(GuiceResource.class);

                 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 params.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, "unbound");
                 serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);
             }
         }
     });
```

Sadly I could not get more information about the registration process of jersey resources.

Any help would be appreciated. Of course I can provide additional info, if needed!
Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It becomes fairly standard that i answer my own question, but I found the answer from a Guice 2 Thread but fortunately it works with Guice 3 and Jersey 1.8

```
/*
* The following line will scan ausbdsoccer.server.resources package for Jersey Resources
*/
params.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages","ausbdsoccer.server.resources");
```

There you go.

Dont forget to pass the params Map to your GuiceContainer.class!

Comment: Thanks, really helpful! I had the very same problem.